# SQL Server sp_clean_db_free_space

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just want to ask if I can use the stored procedure `sp_clean_db_free_space` as part of preventive maintenance?

What are the pros and cons of this built in stored procedure? I just want to hear the inputs of someone who already uses this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would typically not need to explicitly run this, unless you have specific reasons.

Quoting from SQL Server Books Online's [page for `sp_clean_db_free_space`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408732(v=sql.110).aspx):

> Delete operations from a table or update operations that cause a row
>   to move can immediately free up space on a page by removing references
>   to the row. However, under certain circumstances, the row can
>   physically remain on the data page as a ghost record. **Ghost records
>   are periodically removed by a background process**. This residual data
>   is not returned by the Database Engine in response to queries.
>   However, in environments in which the physical security of the data or
>   backup files is at risk, you can use `sp_clean_db_free_space` to clean
>   these ghost records.

Notice that SQL Server already has a background process to achieve the same result as `sp_clean_db_free_space`.

The only reason you might wish to explicitly run `sp_clean_db_free_space` is if there is a risk that the underlying database files or backups can be compromised and analysed. In such cases, any data that has not yet been swept up by the background process can be exposed. Of course, if your system has been compromised in such a way, you probably also have bigger problems on your hands!

Another reason might be that you have a **time-bound requirement** that deleted data should not be retained in any readable form. If you have only a general requirement that is not time-bound, then it would be acceptable to wait for the regular background process to perform this automatically.

The same page also mentions:

> Because running sp_clean_db_free_space can significantly affect I/O
>   activity, we recommend that you run this procedure outside usual
>   operation hours.
>
> Before you run sp_clean_db_free_space, we recommend
>   that you create a full database backup.

To summarize:

- You'd use the `sp_clean_db_free_space` stored procedure only if you have a time-bound requirement that deleted data should not be retained in any readable form.
- Running `sp_clean_db_free_space` is IO intensive.
- Microsoft recommend a full database backup prior to this, which has its own IO and space requirements.

Take a look at this related question on dba.stackexchange.com: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11280/how-can-i-truly-delete-data-from-a-sql-server-table-still-shows-up-in-notepad/11281